# Error to install the Google Play Service in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-api-3

I got a error in the Android Studio, I'm trying install the google play services because I want work with google maps, but it's  throwing a error:

> Downloading Google Play services, revision 29 Failed to create
>   directory C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\temp Done.
>   Nothing was installed.

Somebody have some knowledge about this?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add play services dependencies in your apps gradle?  `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'` ... also refere here to set up google play services https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project